# Make function only callable from one class

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a class `LoggingManager` and a protocol `LoggingHandler` with a single method `send(LoggingEvent)`.
`LoggingManager` keeps a List of `LoggingHandler`s.
I want `LoggingManager` to be the *only* class that is allowed to call `send(LoggingEvent)` from the LoggingHandler and classes that use the protocol should implement the `send(LoggingEvent)` method.

I tried putting `LoggingHandler` and `LoggingManager` into the same file and marking `send(LoggingEvent)` as **fileprivate**.
However, it is not allowed in Protocols.

Is there a way to make it work?

`LoggingManager.swift`

```
import Foundation

public struct LoggingEvent {
    var eventName: String
    var eventParams: [String: Any]

    public init(_ name: String, _ eventParams: [String: Any]) {
        self.eventName = name
        self.eventParams = eventParams
    }

    public init(_ name: String) {
        self.eventName = name
        eventParams = [String: Any]()
    }

    mutating public func addParameter(_ eventName: String, _ eventValue: Any) {
        self.eventParams[eventName] = eventValue
    }
}

public protocol LoggingHandler {
    func logEvent(_ event: LoggingEvent) ///<--- Only LoggingManager should call this function, but classes implementing this should override it
}

public class LoggingManager {
    private var loggingHandlers: [LoggingHandler]
    static let shared = LoggingManager()

    private init() {
        loggingHandlers = []
    }

    public func registerLoggingHandler(_ loggingHandler: LoggingHandler) {
        loggingHandlers.append(loggingHandler)
    }

    public func logEvent(_ event: LoggingEvent) {
        for handler in loggingHandlers {
            handler.logEvent(event)
        }
    }
}
```

`FirebaseLogger.swift`

```
class FirebaseLogger: LoggingHandler {
    var firebaseApp: FirebaseApp?

    public init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.app()
    }

    func logEvent(_ event: LoggingEvent) {
        Analytics.logEvent(event.eventName, parameters: event.eventParams)
    }
}
```

`LogLoggingHandler.swift` (just prints to the console)

```
public class LogLoggingHandler: LoggingHandler {
    public func logEvent(_ event: LoggingEvent) {
        let name = event.eventName
        let description = event.eventParams.description
        print("LogEvent: \(name) \(description)")

    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds as if you don't really understand how to use the protocol. Can you show the code? You don't need to have "a list of LoggingHandlers". You can have your "delegate" as optional, and assign it multiple times by the current object you're working with. Show some code and I will try to help. Show the ```LoggingManager``` class, and show 1-2 other places where you use the delegate.

Comment: @Starsky It is very common for a Logging manager to require a list of Logging handlers. You may log to multiple destinations. (My own logging framework works exactly the same way.)

Comment: I like Rob's answer, but I encourage you to rethink the design. If this is really necessary for correctness (the handler and manager share some synchronized state), then I encourage you to rethink that state. If not, what problem is this solving? If your concern is that callers misuse the API by accident, then I'd rename things before trying to enforce things in the compiler. How do you plan to test the handlers? What if you want a handler that wraps another handler (to add information to every message for example)? How would you implement that? This design limits you for little obvious value.

Comment: @Starsky Think of Logging as some kind of User data collecting like Firebase.
We want to send data to Firebase and other backends (indeed, our own backend).
The `LoggingManager` has a function `registerHandler(LoggingHandler)`
and you call `sendEvent(LoggingEvent)` on the `LoggingManager`, not the `LoggingHandler itself`. The Manager delegates the event to the registered Handlers. That's why i want the Manager to have exclusive access to the send method of the Handlers.
I've added my current code

Comment: I don't understand the comment "that's why I want the Manager to have exclusive access." What bad thing would happen if some part of the system were to *want* to log exclusively to Firebase and not all the other loggers? Do you believe it's likely that another developer would do this by mistake? Why make it impossible?

Comment: At first I did not understand your question correctly, but after seeing your code, I understood your dilemma. I think Rob's answer should do the trick for you.

Comment: @RobNapier this is not a good argument tbh. Having a single point where logging happens is much better than multiple loggers scattered in the project. I could pass a filter to the Logging Manager anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the prettiest solution but here's an idea. In your first file you could define these types:

```
struct LoggingSecurity {
    fileprivate init() {}
}

class LoggingManager {
    private let handlers: [LoggingHandler]
    private let security: LoggingSecurity

    init(handlers: [LoggingHandler]) {
        self.handlers = handlers
        self.security = .init()
    }

    func broadcast(event: LoggingEvent) {
        handlers.forEach { handler in
            handler.send(
                event: event,
                securedBy: security
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Since the `LoggingSecurity.init` method is marked as `fileprivate` the only class that can instantiate `LoggingSecurity` is `LoggingManager`.

Then in your other files you could define these types:

```
struct LoggingEvent {
    let data: String
}

protocol LoggingHandler {
    func send(event: LoggingEvent, securedBy security: LoggingSecurity)
}

class PrintLoggingHandler: LoggingHandler {
    func send(event: LoggingEvent, securedBy security: LoggingSecurity) {
        print("LOG: \(event.data)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Feels like a hack, but does the job. Thank you!

Comment: Another thing I just thought of is that you could make your `LoggingEvent` data structure initializer fileprivate. Then you wouldn't need the klunky `LoggingSecurity` data structure. This would work as long as other data types don't need to instantiate `LoggingEvent`